# Securing api subdomain with single certificate

Tags: ssl, digital-ocean, dokku, lets-encrypt

I have secured my www.domain.com, but I also want to secure the api.domain.com subdomain

How is this possible with a single letsencrypt domain?

Im running

Dokku
DigitalOcean

Answer (score 0):

Let's Encrypt certificates are SAN certificates. It means you can bundle more than one domain/hostname in the same certificate.

The correct procedure depends on what tool/client you used to issue the certificate. Simply configure it with the domains you want.

Two important notes: the number of domains/hostnames is currently limited to 100. Moreover, while in public beta, Let's Encrypt limits the issuance to 5 certificates per domain. Therefore, if you reissue a certificate and/or issue a new one with multiple domains, you'll get closer to the limit.

Just beware of that. [Be sure to read the rate-limit section here](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/quick-start-guide/1631?u=weppos).